# how to create 100% div height?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I want to know how to make website 100% height like this?

[image]

website is https://ahmadawais.com/
see every div is 100% weight

I have another question. Look at the bottom right of site. A mouse icon which mention "click me" and drop 100% weigh next. How can I create this icon?

Comment: he has height set to 100% on the div that uses the background image

Comment: That would be using the CSS `height: 100%;` (and don't forget the `body` and `html` tags) and `cursor`.

Comment: no his every div is 100% height not for the image. and I want to know about 100% window function in javascript also if it possible in css. Thank you

Comment: The mouse icon should be a separate question, assuming it was created with code and isn't just an image.

Comment: Icon is CSS, use developer tools in your browser to inspect and _learn_ how it was done.

Answer (score 0):

His div height: `height: 100vh;`

This will make the div 100% of your screen height.
I actually don't know how to create such a mouse, but I atleast answered your first question.